# Changing source of image with an image of different size, won't resize in IE

Tags: javascript, scripting, dhtml

I'm trying to create a very simple gallery using javascript. There are thumbnails, and when they're clicked the big image's source gets updated. Everything works fine, except when I try it in IE the images' size stays the same as the inital image's size was. Let's say initial image is 200x200 and I click on a thumbnail of a 100x100 image, the image is displayed but it is streched to 200x200. I don't set any width or height values, so I guess the browser should use image's normal size, and so does for example FF.

here's some code:

```
function showBigImage(link)
{
 var source = link.getAttribute("href");
 var bigImage = document.getElementById("bigImage");
 bigImage.setAttribute("src", source);
 return false; /* prevent normal behaviour of <a> element when clicked */
}
```

and html looks like this:

```
<ul id="gallery">
 <li>
  <a href="images/gallery/1.jpg">
   <img src="images/gallery/1thumb.jpg">
  </a>
 </li>
    (more <li> elements ...)
</ul>
```

the big image is created dynamically:

```
function createBigImage()
{
 var bigImage = document.createElement("img");
 bigImage.setAttribute("id", "bigImage");
 bigImage.setAttribute("src", "images/gallery/1.jpg");

 var gal = document.getElementById("gallery");
 var gal_parent = gal.parentNode;
 gal_parent.insertBefore(bigImage, gal);
}
```

There's also some code setting the onclick events on the links, but I don't think it's relevant in this situaltion. As I said the problem is only with IE. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like IE is computing the `width` and `height` attributes for `#bigImage` when it is created and then not updating them when the `src` is changed. The other browsers are probably noting that they had to compute the image dimensions themselves so they recompute them when the `src` is changed. Both approaches are reasonable enough.

Do you know the proper size of the image inside `showBigImage()`? If you do, then set the `width` and `height` attributes explicitly when you change the `src`:

```
function showBigImage(link) {
    var source   = link.getAttribute("href");
    var bigImage = document.getElementById("bigImage");
    bigImage.setAttribute("src",    source);
    bigImage.setAttribute("width",  the_proper_width);
    bigImage.setAttribute("height", the_proper_height);
    return false;
}
```

If you don't know the new dimensions then change `showBigImage()` to delete `#bigImage` and create a new one:

```
function createBigImage(src) {
    var bigImage = document.createElement("img"); 
    bigImage.setAttribute("id",  "bigImage");
    bigImage.setAttribute("src", src || "images/gallery/1.jpg");

    var gal = document.getElementById("gallery");
    gal.parentNode.insertBefore(bigImage, gal);
}

function showBigImage(link) {
    var bigImage = document.getElementById("bigImage");
    if(bigImage)
        bigImage.parentNode.removeChild(bigImage);
    createBigImage(link.getAttribute("href"););
    return false;
}
```